# Create JPG/PNG in Windows10 Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

In Windows Explorer, the context menu only has "create bitmap file", there is no "create PNG file" or "create JPG file". The work around is to open mspaint then save, then copy/cut folder path from Explorer then paste it into the save dialog then enter then input file name then save - too complex.

How to insert context menu items that can create PNG/JPG file - using some Windows built-in feature or open source software instead of closed soure 3rd party software?

Comment: You can save directly from **Paint** to a variety of formats. You select this from the `Save as type` drop-list in the `Save/Save As` dialog. We can create **New** options for the filetypes you mentioned, but how do you want them to behave? Launch Paint or create an empty file you can right-click & select an Edit option?

Comment: To create new file with paint, you need to select the folder and change the format which need too manu clicks. The purpose is just to create a new file there. Then ***Enter*** will launch an editor.

Comment: But the default action for those types is **Open** (for viewing, usually in **Photos**), so _<Enter>_ when a file is selected does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a PNG template file and then add this template to your New context menu options.

To create a file template, just execute the program associated with the designated file-type and create a blank or custom file with the specified extension (ie. template.png).  Make sure you place this template in C:\Windows\ShellNew folder.

Create the following reg file by copying the content to a text file and name it
add-PNG-template-to-new-context-menu.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
"FileName"="C:\\Windows\\ShellNew\\template.png"
```

Run the .reg file to add the PNG template to your New context menu options.

To use this reg file with other filetypes, just change the ShellNew entry for the desired filetype and make sure the template you create is in the ShellNew folder.

Comment: Fantasic. Windows 10 doesn't have ShellNew folder. I guess it doesn't matter where the file is put? Even more fantastic is you can create new non-blank files as well.